# $6n^3+\cos^3n\dots$ Using Comparison Test

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have a practice question which I can't figure why the solution comparison is true in the explanation:

$$\frac{6 n^{3}+\cos ^{3} n+5}{5 n^{6}+3 \cos ^{2}(n)+4}$$

Their explaination is:

$-1\leq \cos^3n \leq 1 $ and $ 0 \leq \cos^2n \leq 3$

$\frac{6 n^{3}+\cos ^{3} n+5}{5 n^{6}+3 \cos ^{2}(n)+4} \leq \frac{6 n^{3}+6}{5 n^{6}+4} \leq \frac{12}{5 n^{3}}  $

But I don't understand why I can't just make the comparison:

$\frac{6 n^{3}+\cos ^{3} n+5}{5 n^{6}+3 \cos ^{2}(n)+4} \leq \frac{6}{5 n^{3}}  $

Thanks.

Comment: Your inequality is not correct. How did you get that?

Comment: Your comparison is not an inequality, but rather the function approaches it as $n$ tends to infinity.

Comment: The question is to use a comparison test for $$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{6 n^{3}+\cos ^{3} n+5}{5 n^{6}+3 \cos ^{2} n+4}
$$ and then is used the explanation as a solution for convergence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comparison is not an inequality but an asymptotic approximation for $n$ large that is

$$\frac{6 n^{3}+\cos ^{3} n+5}{5 n^{6}+3 \cos ^{2}(n)+4} \sim \frac{6}{5 n^{3}}$$

as $n \to \infty$ indeed

$$\frac{6 n^{3}+\cos ^{3} n+5}{5 n^{6}+3 \cos ^{2}(n)+4}=\frac{6}{5 n^{3}}\frac{1+\frac{\cos ^{3} n}{6n^3}+\frac{5}{6n^3}}{1+3 \frac{\cos ^{2}(n)}{5n^6}+\frac{4}{5n^6}}$$

with

$$\frac{1+\frac{\cos ^{3} n}{6n^3}+\frac{5}{6n^3}}{1+3 \frac{\cos ^{2}(n)}{5n^6}+\frac{4}{5n^6}}\to 1$$

---

**Edit**

For the given series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{6 n^{3}+\cos ^{3} n+5}{5 n^{6}+3 \cos ^{2} n+4}$$

we can conclude in both ways by the inequality ([direct comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test)) or by the asymptotic approximation ([limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20limit%20comparison%20test%20%28LCT%29%20%28in,either%20both%20series%20converge%20or%20both%20series%20diverge.)).

Answer (score 2):

User user has given an answer explaining how the comparison you are making can be made to answer the underlying convergence question, as a limit *ratio* comparison. I will restrict this answer to an explanation why you can't just make the direct upper-bound comparison that you made.

The practice question's upper bound, $12\over5n^3$, holds for *all* $n$, whereas your upper bound does not. In fact,

$${6n^3+\cos^3n+5\over5n^6+3\cos^2n+4}\le{6\over5n^3}\implies5n^3\cos^3n+25n^3\le18\cos^2n+24\implies20n^3\le42\implies n\le1$$

so the comparison (for $n\gt1$) actually goes the other way, which makes it useless for proving convergence.

The broader message here is that, in proving things mathematically, the individual, step-by=step assertions you make must be *true*. There is a useful role for imprecise, even sloppy, *thinking* when solving mathematical problems (e.g., "Oh, the $6n^3$ and $5n^6$ dominate everything else, so I can throw all the small stuff away"), but at the same time it's important to be able to turn those intuitions into something rigorously true.